# Google Speech Recognition API

Tags: google-api, speech-recognition, speech

I'm trying to use the Google Speech API v2 (at address `https://www.google.com/speech-api/v2/recognize?...`)

I need to use my Api Key, but when I use it I get `error 403 Forbidden`

When I use an API key that was on the example project I downloaded it is working fine.

I saw that at the Google Developers Console I can enable a lot of api options, but didn't find any Speech-API option. Is there anything else I need to enable to get access to this API using my key?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Instructions are here : http://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/api-keys

!! Do not forget to activate the API "Speech API" in "APIs" under "APIS & AUTH" !!

Answer (score 1):

According to [chromium](http://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/api-keys) that there is no quota for google speech to text APIs anymore.so you will not found it in your google cloud project console

[image]

Comment: hey Ahmed can you answer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46211187/what-is-the-google-cloud-speech-api-url

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this API is available to everyone, but here is a github project that provides a valid key. You should try with this key.

https://github.com/gillesdemey/google-speech-v2

Comment: Especially as he removed his key :)

Answer (score 0):

This is an old post, but hopefully it will help someone.
I couldn't find the Speech API listed under the popular APIs on https://console.developers.google.com/ either. You have to search for the Speech API using the "Search all 100 + APIs" search field.

Comment: Not showing in the "Search all 100 + APIs" search either (or at least not if you aren't subscribed - which is the point of step 1 explicitly mentioned in the accepted response).

Comment: @DanCornilescu - I don't know what's wrong with your search.  I'm not subscribed to any list, but when I go to the google dev console, click "enable APIs" and put "speech" in the search box, I get a link "Google Cloud Speech API".  Seems to work fine for me.

Comment: @Jules I can see it now as well, it seems things changed in the past 7 months or so.

Comment: @DanCornilescu AFAICT, it was added to that list some time around the end of march, or maybe very early april... if you leave browsers open for a while, perhaps you had a cached version?

Answer (score -3):

In order to use the service you need to:

- get a developer key (see above answers for instructions)
- send a **mono** flac audio file to http://www.google.com/speech-api/v2/recognize (Google doesn't accept stereo audio anymore)
- specify your audio file's sampling **rate** (e.g. `16000`, `44100`, etc.) and **Content-Type** as `audio/x-flac` in your HTTP header
- specify values for `key`, `client` and `lang` parameters in the url

Here is a `wget` example with full parameters and header:

```
wget -q --post-file file.flac --header="Content-Type: audio/x-flac; rate=16000" -O - "http://www.google.com/speech-api/v2/recognize?client=chromium&lang=en_US&key=AIzaSyAcalCzUvPmmJ7CZBFOEWx2Z1ZSn4Vs1gg"
```

Note that the free service is limited to 50 requests/day for a developer key.

[This repository](https://github.com/amsehili/gspeech-rec) offers a shell script to use the API from the command line (including voice recording).