# Java Google Speech Recognition API

Tags: java, api, google-api, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

I developed a Java Application that used Google Speech Recognition, but from few days/weeks ago it doesn't work, i'm receiving this message.

> java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403

I saw a little bit information about what is happening in [this Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23608863/google-speech-recognition-api).

After that, i registered in https://console.developers.google.com and then i'm trying to use the following URL and i'm having the same response.

> https://www.google.com/speech-api/v2/recognize?output=json&lang=es-EN&key=MY_KEY

Furthermore, in the console developers i'm not seeing in any place some API that it's called speech recognition or similar :(

Anybody has a solution? Thanks

Comment: Sure, use other APIs, there are many of them.

Answer (score 2):

Google shutdown the V1 API. Luckily, there is handy unofficial Java implementation for the new v2 version located [here](https://github.com/The-Shadow/java-speech-api).

A key is required to get it working. You need to also subscribe to the chromium developers newsletter to be able to see the option for that key. Full instructions are included on the wiki of the project.

Comment: I can't see the Speech API option in my list of APIs. Any idea why?

Comment: You have to be a member of the Chromium developer newsletter with the email of the account you are using. Just follow the instructions on the wiki.

Comment: I subscribed there and still can't see it. Is that possible?