# google action package how to define custom slot types?

Tags: actions-on-google, google-home

Hi this is a question about: google home, action sdk, gactions.exe

at https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/rest/Shared.Types/QueryPatterns
Are so called query pattern with custom types but when I try to add them to my action.json and than update via gaction it always says customTypes is an unknown Parameter.

Does someone have an working example with ApiVersion: 2 ?

Is there somewhere in general an larger example of this json. To better see how all works together? After 2 hours research I cant find anything.

Thanks and best regards

**Update: EDIT that works BUT only as intent to start the Skill/APP not inside the APP**

Its Still not change the Speech to text.

edit: that work:

```
 {
      "actions": [
        {
          "description": "Default Welcome Intent",
          "name": "MAIN",
          "fulfillment": {
            "conversationName": "cloud fleet manager"
          },
          "intent": {
            "name": "actions.intent.MAIN",
            "trigger": {
              "queryPatterns": [
                "talk to cloud fleet manager",
                "welcome at cloud fleet manager",
                "ask cloud fleet manager"
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "description": "first text Intent",
          "name": "hallo2",
          "fulfillment": {
            "conversationName": "cloud fleet manager"
          },
          "intent": {
            "name": "com.cfm.hallo2",
            "trigger": {
              "queryPatterns": [
                "(hello)? to cloud fleet manager",
                "hallo $Test:text cloud fleet manager"
              ]
            },
            "parameters": [
              {
                "name": "text",
                "type": "Test"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ],
      "types": [
        {
          "name": "$Test",
          "entities": [
            {
              "key": "bmw",
              "synonyms": [
                "B M W"
              ]
            },
            {
              "key": "benz",
              "synonyms": [
                "benz"
              ]
            }
          ],
          "isUserDefined": false
        }
      ],
      "conversations": {
        "cloud fleet manager": {
          "name": "cloud fleet manager",
          "url": "https://a69fa73a.ngrok.io/google",
          "fulfillmentApiVersion": 2
        }
      }
    }
```

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B8G3pDr3aWiwZjU1akREdTZNQ1U

Comment: Can you update your question to include an actions.json file that you are trying to get to work with QueryPatterns and that does not?

Comment: It sounds like you figured it out but for anyone else looking for information about custom slots take a look at: https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/guides/library/python/extend/custom-actions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have custom slots like names of People or Ships.

To get Custom Words like names. Correctly matched I found that the adding of speech bias hints is working quite well.

You can find informations here:

https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/rest/Shared.Types/AppResponse#Suggestion

Answer (score 1):

I got it after two days more trying and reading.

At first I forgot one dollar sign. Secondly user defined intents in action.json package are only working as start trigger.

And with a larger set of names it seems like this types dont change anything at the Speech to text model.

So dtrange names like "Moreton Bay" is still not correctly recognized when its in the type field. And need to be figured out with very difficult Text parsing later.